# How to apply a function to a value inside a constructor in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have my constructor defined as

```
data MuOp = N  (Name, Name)
          | QN (QName, QName)
          | QO (QOp, QOp)
          | E  (Exp, Exp)
          | D  (Decl, Decl)
          | L  (Literal, Literal)
          | G  (GuardedRhs, GuardedRhs)
```

And I have a few operations on the tuples such as

```
same :: MuOp -> Bool
same (N (a,b)) = a == b
same (QN (a,b)) = a == b
same (QO (a,b)) = a == b
same (E (a,b)) = a == b
same (D (a,b)) = a == b
same (L (a,b)) = a == b
same (G (a,b)) = a == b
```

How ever, it looks ugly to repeat it for multiple functions. Is there any way to define some function such as `apply` where

```
apply :: ((a,a) -> c) -> MuOp -> c
apply f (N (a,b)) = f (a, b)
apply f (QN (a,b)) = f (a, b)
apply f (QO (a,b)) = f (a, b)
apply f (E (a,b)) = f (a, b)
apply f (D (a,b)) = f (a, b)
apply f (L (a,b)) = f (a, b)
apply f (G (a,b)) = f (a, b)
```

So I can just say `same = apply (\(a,b) -> a == b)` or `fEq c -> apply (\(a,b) -> a == c)`

My current definition produces this error.

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Name’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for apply :: ((a, b) -> c) -> MuOp -> c
      at src/Test/MuCheck/MuOp.hs:28:10
Relevant bindings include
  f :: (a, b) -> c (bound at src/Test/MuCheck/MuOp.hs:29:7)
  apply :: ((a, b) -> c) -> MuOp -> c
    (bound at src/Test/MuCheck/MuOp.hs:29:1)
In the expression: a
In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘(a, b)’
```

Comment: Do you understand why you get that error?  It is an important part to understanding many of the possible answers.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson sorry, has been experimenting and pasted the wrong definition

Comment: But my same question applies.

Comment: @rahul: Think about your definition of `apply` carefully: are all the `b` variables of the same type in each case?  Remember that although `apply` is a polymorphic function, the *caller* gets to decide what the type variable `a` is going to be (a.k.a. "a rigid type variable").

Comment: @rahul: You will need to use the Rank2Types extension.  This way, you can ask for a function in which the callee (`apply`) can arbitrarily choose which specialization of `==` to use.

Comment: @Rufflewind thanks, I see what you mean.

Comment: @Rufflewind So apply becomes `forall c. (forall a. Eq a => (a,a) -> c) -> MuOp -> c`. If you would like to add this answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson The error is due to my usage of same f applying to different types in the same function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about your definition of `apply` carefully: are all the `b` variables of the same type in each case? Remember that although `apply` is a polymorphic function, the caller gets to decide what the type variable `a` is going to be (a.k.a. "a rigid type variable" in the error message).

Look at, for example, these two cases:

```
apply :: ((a, a) -> c) -> MuOp -> c
apply f (N  (a, b)) = f (a, b)
apply f (QN (a, b)) = f (a, b)
...
```

In the first line `a` and `b` are both of type `Name`, but in the second line `a` and `b` are both of type `QName`.  Since the *caller* gets to decide what the type variable `a` is, you don't really get to choose between `Name` and `QName` arbitrarily.

**The solution is to use rank-2 types:**

```
{-# Language Rank2Types #-}

apply :: (forall a . Eq a => (a, a) -> c) -> MuOp -> c
apply f (N  (a, b)) = f (a, b)
apply f (QN (a, b)) = f (a, b)
...
```

The previously implicit quantifier `forall a .` has been made explicit and pushed inside the left side of the function arrow.  (Additionally, the `Eq` constraint has been added, but that is a minor detail.)  By doing so, you allow the *callee* (i.e. `apply`) to instantiate the type variable `a` with any type that satisfies the `Eq` constraint.

Comment: The type `forall a . Eq a => (a, a) -> c` looks very similar to `Bool -> c`: what else can `f` do beyond checking whether the two pair components are equal? My feeling is that this is guaranteed by parametricity. If that's the case, there aren't many meaningful `f`s to pass to `apply` :-/

Comment: It could be generalized to `apply :: Q => Proxy c -> (forall a . c a => a -> a -> c) -> MuOp -> c`, where `Q` is a constraint that says every type inside MuOp is an instance of `c`.